# SQL query to find users for monthly anniversary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to write a query that find users who are celebrating a monthly anniversary with my company so we can trigger an email to them (i.e., if today's date is 3/27, it would find people who signed up on 1/27, 2/27, 3/27, 4/27, etc., regardless of year).

My method is to find users whose "day" part of their sign-up date equals the "day" part of today's date.

```
SELECT [User Id],[Sign Up Date] 
  FROM [Monthly Account Update] 
 WHERE DATEPART(DAY,[Sign Up Date]) = DAY(GETDATE())
```

However, this of course doesn't work for these scenarios:

1. At the end of February, I wouldn't get the chance to email people with 29, 30 and 31 monthly anniversary days, as the don't happen. Ideally, when it's February 28th, I'd just like to lump in people with 29, 30 and 31 dates.
2. For every other month where the date ends in a 30th, I wouldn't get to email people with 31st dates. Ideally here, I'd just like to lump in people with 30 and 31 dates.

Can either of those things be accomplished with a SQL query?

Comment: What about on the first (or 15th) of the month instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need a more complicated `where` clause.  Here is a brute force method:

```
SELECT [User Id],[Sign Up Date]
FROM [Monthly Account Update]
WHERE day([Sign Up Date]) = DAY(GETDATE()) or
      (month(getdate()) in (4, 6, 9, 11) and day(getdate()) = 30 and DAY([Sign Up Date]) = 31) or
      (month(getdate()) in (2) and day(getdate()) = 28 and DAY([Sign Up Date]) in (29, 30, 31))
```

If its feb, look for 28th.

Answer (score 1):

Some complicated answers here!  We can simplify greatly:

```
create function dbo.fnIsMonthlyAnniversary(
    @startDate date,
    @comparisonDate date
)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @retVal bit
    set @retVal = 0

    declare @deltaMonth int

    set @deltaMonth = datediff( mm, @startDate, @comparisonDate )

    if dateadd( mm, @deltaMonth, @startDate ) = @comparisonDate
    begin
        set @retVal = 1
    end

    return @retVal
end

-- usage:
select dbo.fnIsMonthlyAnniversary( '2012-12-31', CONVERT( date, getdate() ) )
```

for your usage:

```
SELECT [User Id],[Sign Up Date] 
  FROM [Monthly Account Update] 
 WHERE 1 = dbo.fnIsMonthlyAnniversary( [Sign Up Date], CONVERT( date, getdate() ) )
```

Comment: Are you sure this does the right thing at month ends and in leap years? I'm not saying it doesn't, I'm just asking if you're sure. Something like [@GordonLinoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673272), while perhaps 'more complicated', has the virtue of transparency.

Comment: This has the virtue of leveraging logic already implemented and tested for years and years.  DATEADD handles everything properly, and I tested it myself, but as your reputation could be on the line if you use this code, it's always wise to test it yourself.  It's also really easy to test - create the UDF, then execute the udf using whatever dates you want.  You'll find that '2012-12-31', '2013-02-28' returns 1, for example.

Comment: Nice, I'll be remembering this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Create a permanent table M with a single column [months] populated with the integers from 1 to 1000, and use a query like this:

```
SELECT [User Id],[Sign Up Date]
FROM [Monthly Account Update] AS U
JOIN M
ON CAST(getdate() AS DATE) = DATEADD(month,M.months,U.[Sign Up Date]
```

While it's not very efficient, for a small number of employees, it's no problem to run once a day. You can also add M.months to the SELECT list and get the precise anniversary number of months if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract a month and include each subsequent day from a range of up to 4 days where adding the month does not exceed the current date.

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2/28/2013';
SELECT [Current] = @Today, [MonthAgo] = DATEADD(DAY,t.v,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@Today))
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3)) as t(v)
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,t.v,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@Today))) <= @Today;
```

Result for 2/28/2013:

```
Current    MonthAgo
---------- ----------
2013-02-28 2013-01-28
2013-02-28 2013-01-29
2013-02-28 2013-01-30
2013-02-28 2013-01-31
```

Result for 3/27/2013:

```
Current    MonthAgo
---------- ----------
2013-03-27 2013-02-27
```

Result for 4/30/2013:

```
Current    MonthAgo
---------- ----------
2013-04-30 2013-03-30
2013-04-30 2013-03-31
```

...etc.

**Edit:**

My above answer could be applied by wrapping it into a CTE and then joining to your original query in a straightforward manner. Note that the inline function calls are always limited to four rows for the whole query, so performance impact of the date functions should be negligible:

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE();

; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Current] = @Today, [MonthAgo] = DATEADD(DAY,t.v,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@Today))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3)) as t(v)
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(DAY,t.v,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@Today))) <= @Today
)
SELECT [User Id],[Sign Up Date] 
FROM [Monthly Account Update]
JOIN CTE ON CTE.[MonthAgo] = [Sign Up Date];
GO
```